# TCL causes out of memory heap size error

Tags: java, memory-management, tcl, heap-memory

I have written a TCL which is used within a tool called DMS which is a BOM Management tool

TCL function is to copy certain values from one object to another object. Values which are retrieved from 1st object is stored in an array and I iterate the entire array to set those values in 2nd object.

When I execute this TCL using .bat file there is no memory issue. but when the same TCL is executed within the tool [DMS], it is executed as javaw.exe process and out of memory heap error is thrown.

I tried increasing the heap size allocated to the tool[DMS]but I could not increase heap size beyond 1600MB.

I also tried to unset all the variable used while iterating the array in TCL. But that doesn't help

Is there any way I could release the memory occupied by javaw.exe process in TCL or is there any way I could handle this out of memory issue in TCL other than increasing heap memory

Please share your suggestion

Comment: The [tag:tcl] tag is for questions relating to Tool Command Language. Is this what you are asking about, or is it some other definition of TCL?

Comment: Yes I'm referring the same tool command language. I have a tcl file which when executed as stand alone does not cause any issue where as when the same tcl file is made to execute within some tool it results in out of memory heap issue

Comment: OK, I just had to check, because from your description it didn't seem like you were talking about a Tcl script at all. I am not familiar with your setup, but hopefully someone else is. Can you post an excerpt from your code that seems to cause the problem? And the error message, if it's not too long.

Comment: (Please post those by editing the question, not in a comment.)

Comment: This is Tcl embedded inside a JVM? (That tends to be a slightly different version to the stand-alone C version.) If so, you need to use standard JVM mechanisms for memory management.

Comment: Can you write your code to process only a little bit at a time rather than pulling lots of stuff into memory at once? Sometimes that's critical to making a program work…

Comment: Thanks for replying. Even if I try to process little bit at a time, after the completion of execution, memory is not released. Memory is only getting added and it is never released.   Is it possible to release JVM memory from TCL script?

Comment: Is this a Java version of TCL, or is this Java code calling the standard TCL interpreter via JNI?